# AS3 document class trouble

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

I just started using the document class in flash cs6 today...

so I learned how to put things on the stage and remove it...but if I make a chain of it it doesn't really work and gives me an error here this is what I mean...

```
    public var playbtn:SimpleButton;
    public var loadbtn:SimpleButton;
    public var backbtn:SimpleButton;

        public function SkoolBook() {

            playbtn = new play_button;
            addChild(playbtn);
            playbtn.x=200;
            playbtn.y=200;

            playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playbutton);

            function playbutton (MouseEvent) {
                removeChild (playbtn);
                loadbtn = new load1;
                addChild(loadbtn);
                loadbtn.x=500;
                loadbtn.y=500;


            loadbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadbutton);
                  function loadbutton (MouseEvent) {
                removeChild (loadbtn);
                backbtn = new back_button;
                addChild(backbtn);
                backbtn.x=500;
                backbtn.y=500;
        }

            }
```

---

so umm yah I just want a ssimple event that if I click on the play button that button disappears and the load button comes up..and if I click on the load button then my first stage comes up......

is there something here I am misunderstanding... why is this giving me an error?

can somebody please exaplin how to exactly carry out sequences in document class....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it.
If not post the errors.

```
package{
  import flash.events.MouseEvent;

  public class SkoolBook{
    public var playbtn:SimpleButton = new play_button();
    public var loadbtn:SimpleButton = new load1();
    public var backbtn:SimpleButton = new back_button();

      public function SkoolBook() {
          addChild(playbtn);
          playbtn.x=200;
          playbtn.y=200;

          playbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playbutton);
      }
      public function playbutton (evt:MouseEvent) {
            removeChild (playbtn);
            addChild(loadbtn);
            loadbtn.x=500;
            loadbtn.y=500;
            loadbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, loadbutton);
      }
      public function loadbutton (evt:MouseEvent) {
            removeChild (loadbtn);
            addChild(backbtn);
            backbtn.x=500;
            backbtn.y=500;
            // don't forget to add the backbtn function
            //backbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, XXXXXXXX);
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

You'll get errors from having `MouseEvent` all alone in your function definitions:

```
function playbutton (MouseEvent)
```

Should be:

```
function playbutton (mEvent:MouseEvent)
```

This way, your function `playbutton` has a name (`mEvent`) to represent the instance of the `MouseEvent` that is being passed into it.  You'll have to do the same for `function loadbutton (MouseEvent)`.

If you continue to get errors, please be more descriptive and include the error text so it's easier to help :]

Comment: I see thank u good fella :D I have a question I am making an interactive fiction (so like a digital comic with a lot of choices and things..ummm somethinglike Zork) is it more logical to use the time line than the document class? its a lot of choices...

Comment: Well, the "Document Class" is just a subclass of the `MovieClip` object that serves as actionscript’s entry point into your project.  You'll be fine using it instead of throwing code into the first frame of the timeline.

Comment: I see...but which one will be more efficient and easier?

Comment: Easier: Document Class, More Efficient: I have no idea :P